# regex pattern in java is not working

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regex pattern to search for a special kind of file names:

A file name may look like this:

```
fileName_1x1.extension
```

I want to find if the filename has this pattern:

```
_(number)x(number).
```

I pasted the previous path into an online regex generator/tester and it worked with this pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("_\\d(.+)x\\d(.+)\\.");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("fileName_1x1.extension");
return matcher.find();
```

Why isn't this working in Java?

Comment: I don't see why this pattern would work.  What tool did you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be this regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("_\\d+x\\d+\\.");
```

You have `.+` after `\\d` which will match any character 1 or more time after a digit.